# Is it possible to modify uitabbarcontroller height?

Tags: ios, iphone

I heard that if you move tab bar from bottom your your app will be rejected as it's against their policy but i want to modify the height and add a admob banner view and some buttons
It will be rejected if I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible to modify the height. You have to customize the `tabbarcontroller` to achieve this.

Try the [sample project](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController) for this in Github.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the tabBar height like this:

```
CGRect viewFrame=self.tabBar.frame;
        //Sample parameters, add what fits your needs
        viewFrame.origin.y -=30;
   viewFrame.origin.x -=10;
   viewFrame.size.height=150;
   viewFrame.size.width=200;
        self.tabBar.frame=viewFrame;
```

This is for UITabBar not tabBarController in case you created a tab-based project.

Answer (score 2):

Your app might not be rejected. Just because you change the control object of tab doesn't mean any security issues. For example, apple's own app store app on iPad is a tab bar controller, but the control object is `uisegmentcontrol` object.

You can hide or change the tab bar in a tab bar controller very easily. The following code should explain it easily.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tabBar.hidden = YES;

    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height+49, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        }

    }
}
```

Also I suggest you give more thought to this method. [Container Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

However, if apple rejects you can change things very easily. Don't worry a lot to try something new. Maybe apple will get your idea and pay you some royalty to use even :P.

Comment: haha, i don't want to be rejected.. this will cost me extra work and i tried something else

Answer (score 1):

And what about contentViewController? Because if you change heigth (and move position.y), you should increase viewcontroller size too, isn't it?